# Printing .txt file content vertically in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, line-breaks

I am using:

```
<?php $emails = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/files/emails.txt'; ?>
<?php $filecontents = file_get_contents($emails);?>
<?php print $filecontents;?>
```

to print out contents inside a text file. The printed out text should be displayed vertically just like it is displayed inside the text file but it is displayed horizontally once printed out.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need an opening and closing tag (`<?php...?>`) for each line of your code.

Comment: I know. Just keeps it clean. Have to use script tags too .That's why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to look at php's function [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

```
<?php print nl2br($filecontents);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting that in `file_get_contents` , grab that under `file()` and then `implode()` it up using a `<br>` tag.

```
<?php $filecontents = file($emails);?>
<?php print implode('<br>',$filecontents);?>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but @Mazzekazze way is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML requires use of the `<br>` tag to create line breaks (or block level elements). In your code you aren't doing anything to indicate you want a new line. Not even a new line character `\n`.

```
<?php echo "'".$emails."'<br>"; ?>
```